# Preprocessing on mahout classifier training data

Tags: machine-learning, mahout

I am training mahout classifier.Do i need to do stemming,lower casing  and stop word removal on my training data or mahout will take care of this as a part of training process. Below command i am using for training.

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout trainclassifier -i category-training-data -o category-bayes-model -type bayes -ng 1 -source hdfs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does no preprocessing of that kind, no.

Comment: Thanks Sean for Answer . But after doing that kind of pre-processing (mentioned in question) on my data improve accuracy of classifier or not ??

Comment: Probably, because you will tend to ignore signals that don't differentiate classes much (stopwords) and recognize when two strings are actually the same semantic concept, which is what features should be (stemming).